# upload file thru Angular HttpClient with form data and file but multer won't fetch file

Tags: angular, express, httpclient, multer

I'm trying to upload my form data with a image file. However, my http request seems a bit off since it doesn't pass the file to my backend. Either that, or my multer set up is "wrong" since it won't be able to pick up req.file. (It was working when I pass the Http request without the form data) Here is my code. Thank you.

component.html

```
<div class="container" id="createPost">
<form (submit)="createPostx()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name= createPost.title [(ngModel)]= createPost.title placeholder="title">
    <input  type="textarea" name= createPost.desc [(ngModel)] = createPost.desc placeholder="description">
    <input  type="text" name= createPost.image [(ngModel)] = createPost.image placeholder="image link">
    <input  type="number" name= createPost.price [(ngModel)] = createPost.price placeholder="price">
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>

```
button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
```

component.ts

```
export class ListingComponent implements OnInit {
  createPost= {};
  selectedFile: File = null;
  images: Array<any>

  constructor(
    private _postService: PostService,
    private _router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createPostx(){
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this._postService.createPost(this.createPost, uploadData)
    .subscribe(result=>{
    this._router.navigate(["frontPage/listing"])
    })
  }

onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
  }

}
```

post.service

```
  createPost(post,image){
    return this._http.post('/createPost', [image, post])
  }
```

backend

```
app.post("/createPost", upload.single('image'),function(req,res){
console.log(req)
post = Post(req.body);
post._user = req.session.user._id
post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.json({error:err})
    }
    else{
        console.log("success")
        res.json({result:post})
    }
})
})
```

Comment: You should put `createPost` object inside formData `uploadData`. Append all your fields to FormData, and then send to service: `createPost(post: FormData){
    return this._http.post('/createPost', post)
  }`

Comment: I tried that. But I don't know what parameter is FormData asking for. I tried uploadData.append('data',JSON.stringify(this.createPost)). but my backend won't even take it and give me back errors.

Comment: I added a answer so its easier to code. You need to append all your fields separately as FormData. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all inputs from `createPost` object inside formData `uploadData`. Append all your fields to FormData, and then send to service.

```html
<div class="container" id="createPost">
<form (submit)="createPostx()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name= createPost.title [(ngModel)]= createPost.title placeholder="title">
    <input  type="textarea" name= createPost.desc [(ngModel)] = createPost.desc placeholder="description">
    <input  type="text" name= createPost.image [(ngModel)] = createPost.image placeholder="image link">
    <input  type="number" name= createPost.price [(ngModel)] = createPost.price placeholder="price">
    <input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>
    <button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

```js
export class ListingComponent implements OnInit {

  createPostx(){
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('title', this.createPost.title);
    uploadData.append('desc', this.createPost.desc);
    uploadData.append('price', this.createPost.price);
    uploadData.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this._postService.createPost(uploadData)
    .subscribe(result=>{
    this._router.navigate(["frontPage/listing"])
    })
  }

  onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
  }

}
```

```js
createPost(post: FormData){
    return this._http.post('/createPost', post)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by hard coding "this.createPost.title". If I use this.createPost.title in the append. It will give me a typescript error. (error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}') How do I fix that?

Comment: Try to declare `createPost` like this `createPost: any = {};`

Comment: Thnx bro. It helped.

Comment: Glad it helped. For better usability, you may add a class or interface instead of `any`. Like this:  `export class Post {  title: string;  desc: string; price: number;  ...  }`  .Then call `Post` inside `ListingComponent`: `createPost: Post;`